# PowerShell Script: Sorting by Object Size in MBs

Tags: powershell, scripting

Consider the following PowerShell script:

```
Get-Process |
Select-Object @{Name='ID';Expression={$_.Id}}, @{Name='Process Name';Expression={$_.Name}},
@{Name='WS';Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.WorkingSet/1MB)}},
@{Name='Private';Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.PrivateMemorySize/1MB)}},
@{Name='Virtual';Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.VirtualMemorySize/1MB)}} | Sort-Object WS |
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

It seemingly runs without issues. However, as I go through the results, I can see that the sorting of the "Working Set" object is not working as expected (notice how the process orders "106.8" before "11.7", as if it was sorting first by the first digit and then by the second, and so on):

```
  ID Process Name          WS    Private Virtual
  -- ------------          --    ------- -------
1156 svchost               1.9   1.5     73.2   
 628 svchost               10.5  15.4    148.7  
 116 svchost               10.8  4.5     119.4  
 660 chrome                106.8 163.8   601.0  
5708 svchost               11.7  5.1     115.3
```

Any thoughts as to how I could fix this?

I have also tried sorting by "WorkingSet", as in:

```
Sort-Object WorkingSet
```

This ends up not sorting the results at all, though.

Comment: Sort before Select

Comment: Also, don’t use 'Select-Object` in cases like this where you only want to display customised properties.  It is creating a new object for each object you already have and copying the properties, which is an unnecessary overhead.  Use the calculated properties on `Format-Table` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should put Sort-Object before Select-object.

```
Get-Process | Sort-Object WS
```

This will give you desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a property in num for sort and remove after, like this :

```
Get-Process | %{

[pscustomobject]@{
    ID=$_.Id
    'Process Name'=$_.Name
    WS="{0:N1}" -f ($_.WorkingSet/1MB)
    Private="{0:N1}" -f ($_.PrivateMemorySize/1MB)
    Virtual="{0:N1}" -f ($_.VirtualMemorySize/1MB)
    WSNum=$_.WorkingSet
}


} | Sort WSNum | select * -ExcludeProperty WSNum |  ft -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your variable in decimal with a round like it:

```
Get-Process | %{

[pscustomobject]@{
    ID=$_.Id
    'Process Name'=$_.Name
    WS=[math]::Round($_.WorkingSet/1MB, 1)
    Private=[math]::Round($_.PrivateMemorySize/1MB, 1)
    Virtual=[math]::Round($_.VirtualMemorySize/1MB, 1)
}


} | Sort WS | ft -AutoSize
```